# Image loads in Chrome/IE, but not in FF

Tags: html, cross-browser

I am a bit stumped on an error I am getting.
In IE and Firefox, [hitting my site](http://languagesofaustralia.com/), everything loads fine.

However, in Firefox (v30), an image is not loading.
It is trying to hit the wrong path:

http://languagesofaustralia.com/img%5Csmalllogo.png (404)

Where as Chrome and IE correctly get the image with this path:

http://languagesofaustralia.com/img/smalllogo.png (200)

The line of HTML (135 in index.html) appears correct by how I understand it:

So what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used

```
<img id="ealogo" alt="View Logo" src="img\smalllogo.png"> (\) wont take in server
```

Try using this

```
<img id="eaLogo" alt="View Logo" src="img/smalllogo.png"> (/) Try using this slash
```

Answer (score -1):

your link contains backslash so url give error,

you are given 
"http://languagesofaustralia.com/img%5Csmalllogo.png"

it should be 
'http://languagesofaustralia.com/img/smalllogo.png"
'